# How do I solve $\sqrt{x}=x$ to get $x=0$ algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

We all know the solutions of

$$\sqrt{x}=x$$

are $x=0$ and $x=1$, which are easily checked.  If I wanted to solve for the latter solution, I would proceed as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{x}&=&x\\
\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2&=&\left(x\right)^2 \\
x &=& x^2 \\
1 &=& x
\end{eqnarray}

However, I am at a loss to solve the solution $x=0$ in a similar algebraic manner.   Can anyone show me where to begin?

Comment: Be careful when you divide x from both sides. This is actually where you're getting rid of the x = 0 solution. You can instead move the xs to get 0 = x^2 - x = x(x-1), then you get 0 = x or 0 = x -1 -> x = 1

Comment: Set equal to $0$ and factor, once you have a polynomial.

Comment: There's a step at the end where you divide by $x$, but that step is only valid if $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from $x=x^2$:

$$x=x^2$$
$$x^2-x=0$$
$$x\cdot(x-1)=0$$
So, $x=0$ or $x=1$

Comment: Wow, I feel retarded.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you reach $x=x^2$, and you divide with $x$, you are already supposing, that $x \ne 0$, since if $x=0$, you can't divide. If you just stick with $x=x^2$, you will get $x_1=1, x_2=0 (x=x^2 \rightarrow 0=x^2-x=x(x-1))$

Answer (score 1):

When you go from the step $x = x^2$, you divide through the equation by $x$ which implicitly assumes $x\neq 0$, so you have to check if $x = 0$ is a solution as well. However you can also say

$$x^2 = x \implies x^2 - x = 0 \implies x(x-1) = 0 \implies x = 0 \text{ or } x = 1. $$